# LiveCD installer just shows empty disk

Tags: installation, dual-boot

When booting the LiveCD throws some general errors about the filesystem, drm, unhandled intr etc.

When I try ubuntu I get the the ntfs partitons with windows 8 mounted and can do stuff there.

There is 30GB empty space, but the installer shows me /dev/sda is totally empty, not even showing the win8 partitions.

-- edit --

Im trying to install ubuntu 12.10

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 then you may have some problems if you laptop was shipped with Windows 8 preinstalled as Microsoft are trying to lock their customers out of installing alternative operating systems.

You best option is to boot from disk, to do this you will need to go into you BIOS and set the boot order to CD or USB (whichever you are using), the save settings and exit, you will then go into the setup for Ubuntu, you will need to select install alongside Windows and then you will be given the option to set the partition size.

that is the easiest option, i can not remember if it showed up my windows partition when i installed ubuntu as i done it so long ago.

if you have problems try booting into Windows and then removing the partition you have created and put it back with your windows partition then go to boot into Ubuntu live CD and set your partition that way it is much easier

Comment: I know. I removed the preinstalled win8 and installed my own version (without secure boot, uefi stuff etc.) [added some screenshots]

Comment: ok now all you need to do is reallocate the unallocated bit to you main partition, or you could set it as a active drive (say f:) and use it to store files on.

To reallocate it all you have to do is right click on the main partition and click expand

Comment: but I wanted to use the unallocated space for ubuntu :(

Comment: what you need to do then is set it as an actual drive, you do this by right clicking it and pressing assign and then select the letter of the drive you would like to use